# VBScript Regexp Does Not Give Result As Expected

Tags: regex, vbscript

```
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
With regEx
    .Pattern = "\[QUOTE=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/QUOTE\]"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With
string1="[QUOTE=P2]A[/QUOTE]B[QUOTE=P3][QUOTE=P1]C[/QUOTE]D[/QUOTE]E"
response.write regEx.Replace(string1, "")
```

I want **BE** as a result but I get **BD[/QUOTE]E**

Where is the problem?

Comment: Don't use regex for this type of task..

Comment: The quote tags are nested and you won't be able to remove them  with VBScript regex.

Comment: So you want to match any text outside of `[QUOTE]...[/QUOTE]` tags? Can't be done with VBScript regex. .NET has balanced group to handle this, but not VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just do some conversions step by step to get the necessary structure, then retrieve result:

```
string1 = "[QUOTE=P2]A[/QUOTE]B[QUOTE=P3][QUOTE=P1]C[/QUOTE]D[/QUOTE]E"
With New RegExp
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "\[QUOTE=(.*?)\]"
    string1 = .Replace(string1, "[")
    .Pattern = "\[\/QUOTE\]"
    string1 = .Replace(string1, "]")
    .Pattern = "\[[^[]]*?\]"
    Do While .Test(string1)
        string1 = .Replace(string1, "")
    Loop
End With
response.write string1
```